Proving Newton's method is as fast as binary search for finding the square root
Given an integer $N \geq 1$, we're looking for the integer $k$ such that $k^2\leq N < (k+1)^2$.
A relatively easy method to find $k$ would be to use Binary Search (try every integer between $1$ and $N$ starting with $N/2$, eliminating half of the search space at every iteration). If $i$ is the number of iterations used by the binary search, then $i$ is $O(\log(N))$.
Another method to find $k$ is to use Newton's method, which states the following : $$x_{i+1} 
 = x_i-\frac{f(x_i)}{f'(x_i)}$$ where $f(x) = x^2-N$ and $x_0 = \min(N, \frac{N}{2}+1)$.
Using this formula, at every iteration $i$, we can check if the following condition holds: $$\text{floor}(x_{i}^2) \leq N < (\text{floor}(x_{i})+1)^2$$ where the $\text{floor(x)}$ function returns the integer part of any number $x$. If the condition holds, then we find that $k=\text{floor}(x_{i}^2)$
Plotting the number of iterations required using Newton's method for every N, from $1$ to $10^6$, I get :

Looking at this data, I claim (perhaps wrongfully) that the minimum number of iterations required by Newton's method is also $O(\log(N))$, which would mean that, for this particular problem, Newton's method is not faster than Binary search.
How exactly would I go about proving or disproving this claim?
PS: Please note that I am aware that just setting $k = floor(sqrt(N))$ would also give me the desired result. I am trying to look for ways to find $k$ without using the square root function or exponentiation function.

That data is insufficient to determine that Newton's method is $O(\log(N))$. It is not at all clear how you looked at this graph and came to that conclusion

You might have an easier time spotting trends if you instead use $\log(N)$ as your x-axis variable (for a kind of semilog plot)

I don't have a computer sufficiently powerful to plot more values - and if you read my post again, I didn't say it was $O(log(N))$ for sure, I said I "claim" (hypothesis) (or "guess", if you prefer) and I would like to either prove it or disprove it (not using a plot, but with algebra and analysis)

@Skyris -- when comparing No. of iterations for different types of root solvers solving the same function, you should consider the "Ostrowski index" (see Alexander Markowitsch Ostrowski ). It takes into account the computational "drudgery" within every iteration. To compute the derivative within every loop of Newton is more demanding than a simple Binary Search me think.

Newton's method is also known as the babylonian method.  And the "abacus method" of calculating isqrt is a very optimized binary search and is probably the best general purpose algorithm.  The problem with newton's method is that it requires each iteration to do division of an increasingly large number, which is very slow.  The fastest, up to about 53 bits though, is to just do s = (int) sqrt( (float) x ) .

Since you know the exact formula for $f$, compute $f(x_{i+1})/f(x_i)$ with $x_{i+1}\leftarrow x_i-\frac{f(x_i)}{f'(x_i)}$, and then try estimating the formula of $x_i$ you obtain

Where do the steps in your plot occur? If you can find and prove a pattern in these it should solve your question.

@ChrisLewis, I count the number of iteration required inside the for loop for both methods

@Skyris ah, sorry, I wasn't clear. I mean, look at your graph. From $N\approx 100000$ up to $N\approx 350000$, your algorithm takes $10$ or $11$ iterations. Then as $N$ increases, somewhere it switches to taking $11$ or $12$, and so on, creating the appearance of blue rectangles. Basically I'm interested in where the corners of those blue "rectangles" are.

The heuristic arguments below suggest that although the convergence rate of Newton's method to $\sqrt{N}$ increases, it has the complexity $\Omega(\log N)$.
For each natural $i$ let $a_i=x_i-\sqrt{N}$. Then
$$x_{i+1}= x_i-\frac{f(x_i)}{f'(x_i)}=x_i-\frac{x_i^2-N}{2x_i}=
\frac 12\left(x_i+\frac{N}{x_i}\right).$$
This easily yields
$$a_{i+1}=\frac{a_i^2}{2\left(\sqrt{N}+a_i\right)}$$
Thus as far as $a_i\ge \sqrt{N}$ we have $\frac 14\le\frac{a_{i+1}}{a_i}\le \frac 12$.
So I expect we need $\Omega\left(\log \frac{N}{2\sqrt{N}}\right)=\Omega(\log N)$ iterations to ensure $a_i\le \sqrt{N}$.
Then we have $\frac {a_{j+1}}{\sqrt{N}}\le \frac 12\cdot\left(\frac {a_j}{\sqrt{N}}\right)^2$ when $j\ge i$. So $\frac {a_{j+1}}{\sqrt{N}}$ decreases very fast and at least as $2^{i-j}$.

Your question can be loosely framed as Why do subsequent $x$ values in Newton's method follow logarithmic trend when going from $\frac{N}{2}+1$ to $\sqrt{N}$ on the curve $y=x^2-N$.
Firstly,
$$x_{i+1}=x_i-\frac{f(x_i)}{f'(x_i)}\\
x_{i+1}=x_i-\frac{x_i^2-N}{2x_i}\\
x_{i+1}=\frac{N}{2}\left(\frac{x_i}{N}+\frac{1}{x_i}\right)$$
As for large $x_i$, $\frac{1}{x_i}$ deminishes:
$$x_{i+1} \approx \frac{x_i}{2}$$.
You might want to visualise for better understanding.

In the plot, start with $x_0=N/2$. Now, $$x_1=y(x_0)$$
similarly, $$x_2=y(x_1)\\x_3=y(x_2)$$ thus approaching $\sqrt{N}$. Notice the geometrical construction for each $x_i$ and that y is almost linear in that region. And hence for large $N$, this method can be worked out merely with the asymptote of the curve i.e. $y=\frac{x}{2}$ giving a logarithmic descend.
